# PHP form is returning before if statement completes

Tags: php, forms, if-statement

I have a bit of code in which I want a form to appear when the New Player button is clicked. My problem is when I click on the submit button in the form, the validation code does not run. I'm not sure how to force the function to retain control.

The original New Player button calls an external PHP script

```
echo "<form action = '', method = 'post'>";
echo "<button  name = 'showPF', type = 'submit', value = 'New Player'>New Player</button></br>";

echo "</form>";

if(isset( $_POST['showPF'])) { 


require(__DIR__.'/new_player.php');

}
```

The form is then shown and in turn calls a function. This function is the part that never gets executed.

```
echo "<form action = '' method='post'>";
    echo "Player Name: <input type='text' name='playerName'></br>";
    echo "Character Name: <input type='text' name ='charName'></br>";
    echo "Class: <input type='text' name = 'class'></br>";
    echo "Race: <input type='text' name = 'race'></br>";
    echo "Level: <input type = 'int' name = 'level'></br>";
    echo "<button name='add', type = 'submit', value = 'Add Player'>Add Player</button></br>";
    echo "</form>"; 

    if(isset($_POST['add'])){
        addPlayer();
    }
```

The addPlayer() function looks like

```
function addPlayer(){
    //PLAYER NAME
    if(empty($_POST['playerName'])){
    //Player Name is required
        echo "Player Name is required";
    }
    elseif(ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ','', $_POST['playerName'])) == FALSE){
        //Player Name can only be letters and spaces
        echo "Player Name can only contain letters and spaces";
    }
    else{
        $playerName = $_POST['playerName'];
    }


    //CHARACTER NAME
    if(empty($_POST['charName'])){
        $charName = "NULL";
    }
    elseif(ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ','', $_POST['charName'])) == FALSE){
            //Character Name can only be letters and spaces
        echo "Character Name can only contain letters and spaces";
    }
    else{
        $charName = $_POST['charName'];
    }

    //CLASS

    if(empty($_POST['class'])){
        $charClass = "NULL";
    }
    elseif(ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ','', $_POST['class'])) == FALSE){
            //Class can only be letters and spaces
        echo "Class can only contain letters and spaces";
    }
    else{
        $charClass = $_POST['class'];
    }

    //RACE

    if(empty($_POST['race'])){
        $charRace = "NULL";
    }
    if(ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ','', $_POST['race'])) == FALSE){
            //Race can only be letters and spaces
        echo "Race can only contain letters and spaces";
    }
    else{
        $charRace= $_POST['race'];
    }

    //LEVEL

    if(empty($_POST['level'])){
        $charLvl = "NULL";
    }
    if(ctype_digit($_POST['level']) == FALSE){
            //Level must be a number
        echo "Level must be a number";
    }
    else{
        $charLvl= (int)$_POST['lvl'];
    }
}
```

Since I don't know why it's not completing the second if statement I'm not sure how to google my answer. And, I know my code isn't pretty. I'm relearning after 10+ years out of school. Unfortunately, I don't know where else to ask such a novice question.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I would post more complete code. Tough to understand the structure of your application from what you posted. What is the order of these scripts? What does `addPlayer();` execute?

Comment: I would brush up on your HTML as well. You have some issues in there for sure.

Comment: Also, you don't need to echo every line. You can simply end your php. ?> YOUR FORM <?php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `new_player.php` is included only when you submit the `showPF` value, but the second form doesn't have such field. As a solution, just add a hidden field for your second form:

```
<input type='hidden' name='showPF' value='New Player'>
```

Comment: Perfect. That solved my problem and explained why it was happening. Thanks.